# StableBaselines3 Significant Difference between Evaluation and Testing Reward

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am using `stable_baselines3` to train a model to play the Atari Breakout game.
For training efficiency, I am using a vectorized environment of 4 games. Here is the
code regarding training:

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_atari_env
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import SubprocVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import A2C

# train model
train_env = make_atari_env("Breakout-v4", n_envs=4, seed=0, vec_env_cls=SubprocVecEnv)
train_env = VecFrameStack(train_env, n_stack=4)

model = A2C('CnnPolicy', train_env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=200_000)
```

When evaluating the resulting model, I am getting acceptable results of **10.7 reward points
in average**. In the code I am using only one environment for evaluation which is virtually
stacked to be compatible with the model.

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

eval_env = make_atari_env("Breakout-v4", n_envs=1, seed=0, vec_env_cls=SubprocVecEnv)
eval_env = VecFrameStack(eval_env, n_stack=4)

evaluate_policy(model, eval_env, n_eval_episodes=10, render=False)
```

My problem is that when I apply the model on the same evaluation environment without
the `eval_policy` to simulate an actual application of the model on the game, I am getting
really bad results, mostly **0 reward points**.

```py
for i in range(0,10):
  obs = eval_env.reset()
  done = False
  score = 0
  while not done:
    action, _ = model.predict(obs)
    obs, reward, done, info = eval_env.step(action)
    score += reward
  print("Episode:{} Score:{}".format(i, score))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? It seems like the model is not recognizing the environment corrctly in the latter attempt.